# Why does keras function "expand_dims" change the type?

Tags: theano, keras, keras-layer

I'm using keras with a theano backend. Now I have a variable x, which is an theano tensor with a type field "TensorType(float32, 3D)".
I added

```
    from keras import backend as K
```

at the beginning of my file. Then I wrote:

```
    x = K.expand_dims(x, dim = 1)
```

I expected that the type field of x should be "TensorType(float32, 4D)". However, it is "TensorType(float32, (False, True, False, False))", and I cannot figure out the reason. In addition, the document of keras doesn't provide further information of this function, it just says that "Adds a 1-sized dimension at index "dim" ".
Besides, if I perform

```
    x = K.squeeze(x, 1)
```

, the type field of x will be "TensorType(float32, matrix)", which is expected.

Answer (score 1):

The command `expand_dims` has [`dimshuffle`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#theano.tensor._tensor_py_operators.dimshuffle) operation of Theano under the hood. The tuple `(False, True, False, False)` is telling you the dimensions that are broadcastable. You may be aware of the broadcasting abilities of Numpy. It is similar with some key differences.

> From Theano developer: Theano needs all broadcastable dimensions to be declared in the graph before compilation. NumPy uses the run time shape information.

See [this](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/sandbox/broadcasting.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574293/theano-broadcasting-different-to-numpys) for more details.

In the case of your 4-D array, the second dimension i.e. channels is broadcastable. So let us assume that your 4-D array size is `(10,N,20,30)`. Now you can do element-wise multiplication of your 4-D array and another array of size `(10,1,20,30)` without repeating second dimension `N` times. This is called broadcasting. Now you try to multiply your 4-D array and another array of size `(1,N,20,30)`. This will fail since the first dimension is not broadcastable. I hope this is clear.

Comment: I understand the broadcasting mechanism. In fact, I am trying to squeeze a tensor of `TensorType(float32, 4D)` to a tensor of `TensorType(float32, 3D)`, do something on it, and restore it to a tensor of `TensorType(float32, 4D)`. However, I can just restore it to a tensor of `TensorType(float32, (False, True, False, False))`, and I wonder how to restore it to a tensor of `TensorType(float32, 4D)`.